# Get all installed features for Android app bundles

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, android-app-bundle

I have an android application which installs other android applications. I store the details about which features have been installed for an application in shared preferences. But when my app's data is cleared, I lose this info. Now I have to re-populate all the installed features.

Using [PackageInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#splitNames), I can get splitNames and then based on naming pattern, I can consider it as whether it's a feature APK or not.

or I can parse the AndroidManifest.xml of each APK and then check isFeatureSplit flag is set or not.

I am looking for any recommended ways to get this info.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Play Core library? There is a method "getInstalledModules" that returns the list of dynamic features installed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/SplitInstallManager.html#getInstalledModules()

Comment: Thanks for answering. I cannot use Play core libraries as I want my application to work in other Android devices like fire tablets. So I am looking for a way on how to use the APIs from Android.
Also, with Play core library, I can only get installed modules of my app right? but I am looking to get the installed modules for other apps too.

Comment: Do you know anything about this?